# Control a button's enabled state using 3 multi data triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to control a buttons IsEnabled state based on the following conditions. The button should be active only when :

1. Checkbox 1 or Checkbox 2 is checked.
2. Listbox contains atleast 1 list item.

My issue is : I have to use separate MultiDataTrigger for achieving this behavior. When I add the code  to the first multidata trigger, it doesn't work. ie even if list box doesn't have any items, the button is getting enabled.

So I need a solution for this. is there any possible way to include the 3rd multi data trigger condition along with the 2 conditions, so that few lines of code can be saved?

Thanks in advance. Please check my code below.

```
   <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Checkbox1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Checkbox2, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=ListBox, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The MultiTrigger applies the associated setters or actions when all of the conditions are true (binary AND operation).

As mentioned, the trigger will fire on all the conditions being AND'd, which was why it didn't work when you put all the conditions together. The easiest way to produce an OR (without implementing a [IMultiValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), is to have multiple datatriggers (which imply a binary OR operation).

If you are intent on saving lines of code, you can use a DataTrigger instead of the MultiDataTrigger.

```
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=Items.Count }" Value="0">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks